# I need to have the "year" convert to this calendar year 2021 while maintaining the day and month

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Eg.  09/25/2003 would need to reflect 09/25/2021.  Each cell has a different date associated with a "policy" so I'd like a formula that will change just the "year" to reflect this calendar year 2021.  Essentially, read the "year" and add the appropriate number of years to equal 2021, then return the value (cell) to reflect the same day/month with updated year.

Comment: Which calendar? Have you just tried find/replace? Providing the data you're working with, scrubbed of any valuable data, and a mockup of what you'd like it to look like, and listing what you've tried, would help make this a better question.

Comment: I have a lot of data to change each with various years.  the find/replace would be too time consuming.  I was able to use the formula to add days to the date field, however with various years, the formula did not return each row with 2021.  It just added the number of days to that specific date field.

Comment: Use `TextToColumns` to delimit on `/`, change the value of the year, then `concatenate` it back together again.

Comment: Yea, we still need to see the data you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date function. Its parameters are (year, month, day) and it will set the cell to a proper excel date.

For example, if your data is in cell A2, the formula would look like

```
=DATE(2021, MONTH(A2), DAY(A2))
```

The function is available from Excel 2003 onwards.